# get OU Permissions for specific domain

Tags: powershell

I found a script that give you OU permissions for the domain the script is run on.
I want to use the same script from a single domain but scan other domains I specify.

The problem I think is with `$schemaIDGUID = @{}`
When run It's always for the domain the script is running on which is different from the domain I want to run the script on.
Here's the script I modified it to pickup specific domain.

```
$schemaIDGUID = @{}

$domain = "My specific domain name"


$report = @()

$schemaIDGUID = @{}

$ErrorActionPreference = 'SilentlyContinue'
Get-ADObject -Server $domain -SearchBase (Get-ADRootDSE -Server $domain).schemaNamingContext -LDAPFilter '(schemaIDGUID=*)' -Properties name, schemaIDGUID |
 ForEach-Object {$schemaIDGUID.add([System.GUID]$_.schemaIDGUID,$_.name)}
Get-ADObject -SearchBase "CN=Extended-Rights,$((Get-ADRootDSE -Server $domain).configurationNamingContext)" -LDAPFilter '(objectClass=controlAccessRight)' -Properties name, rightsGUID |
 ForEach-Object {$schemaIDGUID.add([System.GUID]$_.rightsGUID,$_.name)}
$ErrorActionPreference = 'Continue'

$OUs  = @(Get-ADDomain -Server $domain | Select-Object -ExpandProperty DistinguishedName)
$OUs += Get-ADOrganizationalUnit -Server $domain -Filter * | Select-Object -ExpandProperty DistinguishedName
$OUs += Get-ADObject -Server $domain  -SearchBase (Get-ADDomain -Server $domain).DistinguishedName -SearchScope OneLevel -LDAPFilter '(objectClass=container)' | Select-Object -ExpandProperty DistinguishedName


ForEach ($OU in $OUs) {
    $report += Get-Acl -Path "AD:\$OU" |
     Select-Object -ExpandProperty Access | 
     Select-Object @{name='organizationalUnit';expression={$OU}}, `
                   @{name='objectTypeName';expression={if ($_.objectType.ToString() -eq '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000') {'All'} Else {$schemaIDGUID.Item($_.objectType)}}}, `
                   @{name='inheritedObjectTypeName';expression={$schemaIDGUID.Item($_.inheritedObjectType)}}, `
                   *
}


$report | Export-Csv -Path ".\$domain.OU_Permissions.csv" -NoTypeInformation
#Start-Process ".\$domain.OU_Permissions.csv"

break



$report |
 Where-Object {-not $_.IsInherited} |
 Select-Object IdentityReference, OrganizationalUnit -Unique |
 Sort-Object IdentityReference

$filter = Read-Host "Enter the user or group name to search in OU permissions"
$report |
 Where-Object {$_.IdentityReference -like "*$filter*"} |
 Select-Object IdentityReference, OrganizationalUnit, IsInherited -Unique |
 Sort-Object IdentityReference
```

Comment: "The problem I think is with [...]" Which problem? What is it that isn't working right now? :-)

Comment: Hi Mathias, let's say I'm on domain A , but I want to scan domain B. When I run the script from domain A I want to specify scan domain B somewhere. I thought I did by adding a $domain variable but when $schemaIDGUID = @{} is running it's always pickup up domain A not B. I think that is the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem has nothing to do with the `$schemaIDGUID` variable.

The problem is this line:

```
$report += Get-Acl -Path "AD:\$OU"
```

The `AD:` drive is mapped to ADWS **on a DC in your home domain**, on module import, so you'll need to explicitly create another drive that maps to the target domain instead:

```
$domain = "other.domain.tld"

# discover naming context + find a DC to query
$defaultNC = (Get-ADRootDSE -Server $domain).defaultNamingContext
$DC = Get-ADDomainController -Server $domain

# map new ADTemp:\ drive
New-PSDrive -Name ADTemp -PSProvider ActiveDirectory -Root $defaultNC -Server $DC
```

For the rest of the script, the only thing you need to change is the previously mentioned line, to:

```
$report += Get-Acl -Path "ADTemp:\$OU"
```

Comment: Hi Mathias, Thanks for the response I added your code right after $domain. and updated $report to inlcude ADTemp. I'm getting the following error.

Comment: New-PSDrive : A referral was returned from the server
At C:\path\OU_permissions.p-s-1.ps1:39 char:1
+ New-PSDrive -Name ADTemp -PSProvider ActiveDirectory -Root $defaultNC -Server $D ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ResourceUnavailable: (ADTemp:PSDriveInfo) [New-PSDrive], ADReferralException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ADProvider:NewDrive:InvalidRoot:ADError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewPSDriveCommand

Comment: @Evo My bad, forgot to target `$domain` with `Get-ADDomainController`, updated

Comment: Thanks Mathias, here's the update hopefully it was added properly.

Comment: # discover naming context + find a DC to query
$defaultNC = (Get-ADRootDSE -Server $domain).defaultNamingContext
$DC = Get-ADDomainController -Server $domain

# map new ADTemp:\ drive
New-PSDrive -Name ADTemp -PSProvider ActiveDirectory -Root $defaultNC -Server $DC

Comment: $report += Get-Acl -Path "ADTemp:\$OU"

Comment: Get-Acl : Cannot find path 'ADTemp:\DC=mydomain,DC=mydomain' because it does not exist.
At .\OU_permissions.p-s-1.ps1:74 char:16
+     $report += Get-Acl -Path "ADTemp:\$OU" |
+                ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (:) [Get-Acl], ItemNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : GetAcl_PathNotFound_Exception,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetAclCommand

Comment: `New-PSDrive -Name ADTemp ...` ran without error?

Comment: Name           Used (GB)     Free (GB) Provider      Root                                                                                                     CurrentLocation
----           ---------     --------- --------      ----                                                                                                     ---------------
ADTemp                                 ActiveDire... //RootDSE/DC=removed,DC=removed

Comment: Get-Acl : Cannot find path 'ADTemp:\DC=removed,DC=removed' because it does not exist.
At .\OU_permissions.p-s-1.ps1:74 char:16
+     $report += Get-Acl -Path "ADTemp:\$OU" |
+                ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (:) [Get-Acl], ItemNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : GetAcl_PathNotFound_Exception,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetAclCommand

Comment: I think it did run properly. But still cannot find path. it's on the correct DC but this RootDSE .. I think is wrong..